# Using JSON to store multiple form entries

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I'm trying to create a note taking web app that will simply store notes client side using HTML5 local storage. I think JSON is the way to do it but unsure how to go about it.

I have a simple form set up with a Title and textarea. Is there a way I can submit the form and store the details entered with several "notes" then list them back?

I'm new to Javascript and JSON so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage ?

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to use json.

1> u can create a funciton on HTML page and call ajax & post data.
here you have to use $("#txtboxid").val(). get value and post it.

2>  use knock out js to bind two way.and call ajax.

here is simple code to call web app. using ajax call.

```
var params = { "clientID": $("#txtboxid") };     

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http:localhost/Services/LogisticsAppSuite.svc/Json/GetAllLevelSubClients",
            contentType: 'application/json',

            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {



            },
            error: function (ErrorResponse) {


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a lib that works just like entity framework. I WILL put it [here](http://cordova.codeplex.com) later, you can follow me there or contact me to get the source code now. Then you can write js code like:

```
var DemoDbContext = function(){ // define your db
    nova.data.DbContext.call(this);
    this.notes=new nova.data.Repository(...); // define your table
}
//todo: make DemoDbContext implement nova.data.DbContext
var Notes = function(){
    this.id=0; this.name="";
}
//todo: make Note implement nova.data.Entity
```

How to query data?

```
var notes = new DemoDbContext().notes.toArray(function(data){});
```

How to add a note to db?

```
var db = new DemoDbContext();
db.notes.add(new Note(...));
db.saveChanges(callback);
```

Comment: here is a full sample: https://cordova.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20nova.data

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the information you want to store you may not need JSON.

You can use the `setItem()` method of `localStorage` in HTML5 to save a key/value pair on the client-side. You can only store string values with this method but if your notes don't have too complicated a structure, this would probably be the easiest way. Assuming this was some HTML you were using:

```
<input type="text" id="title"></input>
<textarea id="notes"></textarea>
```

You could use this simple Javascript code to store the information:

```
// on trigger (e.g. clicking a save button, or pressing a key)
localStorage.setItem('title', document.getElementById('title').value);
localStorage.setItem('textarea', document.getElementById('notes').value);
```

You would use `localStorage.getItem()` to retrieve the values.

[Here is a simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZZxV/1/) I created to show you how the methods work (though not using the exact same code as above; this one relies on a keyup event).

The only reason you might want to use JSON, that I can see, is if you needed a structure with depth to your notes. For example you might want to attach notes with information like the date they were written and put them in a structure like this:

```
{
    'title': {
        'text':
        'date':
    }
    'notes': {
        'text':
        'date':
    }
}
```

That would be JSON. But bear in mind that the `localStorage.setItem()` method only accepts string values, you would need to turn the object into a string to do that and then convert it back when retrieving it with `localStorage.getItem()`. The methods `JSON.stringify` will do the object-to-string transformation and `JSON.parse` will do the reverse. But as I say this conversion means extra code and is only really worth it if your notes need to be that complicated.